# Restore file from HDFS after namenode delete

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, recovery

My namenode server was hacked this weekend and /usr/local/hadoop directory no longer exists. Is it still possible to recover a file that is stored on HDFS? Datanodes are accessible and each contains somewhere in the hierarchy blk_{...} data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have any copy/backup of the name dir, recovering the data will be quite a difficult task. The datanodes are not aware of any concept of a file, only blocks. All of the data exists in those blocks but you would have to manually reconstruct files from their blocks. If you have some specific files of very high importance and not that much data overall you may be able to sift through the blocks to find what you're looking for but I'm not aware of anything better than that.

This is why there are a number of ways to redundantly store multiple copies of the namespace, e.g. by specifying multiple directories in the `dfs.namenode.name.dir` property, and using either a Secondary or a Standby Namenode (see https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#Secondary_NameNode), which act as a remote location storing a copy of the namespace.

Comment: Thanks for your help @krog! Could you tell me what to do if I have a copy of the name dir? I cannot start the hadoop cluster but I can see the content of name dir (in my config it's in /opt/hadoop/hadoop_data/hdfs/namenode/current): edits_... and fsimage_... files.

Comment: @Patrick Can you be more specific about what was deleted? What was the contents of /usr/local/hadoop?

Comment: Actually my server (on the cloud) was put in rescue mode by my host because it has been hacked but the IT has been able to restart the server in normal mode after doing some changes to the firewall. Everything is ok right now. Thanks again for your help @krog, very appreciated.